# Swift: Split string into array at new line - Windows-based text

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, swift2

I am splitting a string into array at new line. The text comes from a server and can be created on multiple platforms. Have no issues with Unix text, however because of the new line definition issues (\n\r vs \n), the text is not split if it is sent from Windows-based server.

I am using this to find a regex expression for a new line and replace it with \n:

```
let stringRev = self.string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "(\r\n|\r|\n)", withString: "\n", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)

let myArray = stringRev.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Is there a way to do it in Swift?

Many thanks!

Comment: are you getting an error? or whats the current output? ... Also instead of regex have you just tried self.string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "\n", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

Comment: Actually - just learned you do not need the optional parameters - .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "\n")

Comment: Depending on what I use ("\r\n" or "\r|), the string is not split either in Windows or on Mac. Just concatenates the new line with the previous. Therefore, I needed a regex to work with all platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use String method enumerateLines:

```
let input = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine3"
var result:[String] = []
input.enumerateLines { (line, _) -> () in
    result.append(line)
}

print(result)  // "["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line3"]\n
```

You can also use componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet and use 
NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet() to break up your lines

```
let input = "Line 1\rLine 2\rLine3"
let linesArray =  input.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.newlineCharacterSet())

linesArray  // ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line3"]
```

If you are planning to use it somewhere else in your code you can create an extension:

```
extension String {
    var linesArray:[String] {
        var result:[String] = []
        enumerateLines { (line, _) -> () in
            result.append(line)
        }
        return result
    }
    var lines: [String] {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    }
}

let input = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine3"
let allLinesSample = input.linesArray  // ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line3"]

let input2 = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine3"
let allLinesSample2 = input2.linesArray  // ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line3"]

let input3 = "Line 1\rLine 2\rLine3"
let allLinesSample3 = input3.lines  // ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line3"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great!